# How to inject a bean in this MongoDB connection case?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, dependency-injection

I have a class that has a MongoDB client member which is injected via constructor args:

```
public class MyDAO {

    private MongoClient mongoClient;

    public MyDAO(MongoClient mongoClient) {
        this.mongoClient = mongoClient;

        /*mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);*/   //This would be the way without using DI.

    }
}
```

My bean configuration file bean.xml is as follows:

```
<bean id="myDao" class="com.example.MyDAO">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
</bean>

<bean id="mongo" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
        <property name="port" value=27017 />
</bean>
```

But I got the error message for the bean.xml as:

```
No setter found for property 'port' in class 'com.mongodb.MongoClient'
```

From MongoDB's [Javadoc](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html), the class `MongoClient` doesn't have setter methods for `host` and `port` properties. So how can I inject values into this Mongo bean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MongoClient` class seems to have a [constructor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html#MongoClient%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
MongoClient(String host, int port)
```

you can therefore use [constructor-based dependency injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection)

```
<bean id="mongo" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
    <constructor-arg name="host" value="localhost" />
    <constructor-arg name="port" value="27017" />
</bean>
```

Note: Because the parameter names are not always available (not through reflection, but through byte code manipulation), you can use the parameter type, which is always available, to distinguish

```
<bean id="mongo" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="localhost" />
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="27017" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks. So if I put `<constructor-arg name="port" value=27017 />` without quote, it will still give me error. `port` is an `int`, why do I need to put it in quote like a `String`?

Comment: Don't remove the quotes and try with set the type of the port argument to `type="java.lang.Integer"`.

Comment: @tonga The quotes are part of the XML format, not something specific to Spring. They are required for attribute values.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So no matter what types of parameter are, we should always use quotes for `value` attribute, right?

Answer (score 2):

Since the `MongoClient` class doesn't have setters for `port` and `host`, but supports passing the `host` and `port` values in the constructor, you can switch `property` with `constructor-arg`.

```
<bean id="mongo" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
    <constructor-arg name="host" type="java.lang.String" value="localhost" />
    <constructor-arg name="port" type="java.lang.Integer" value="27017" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it always better to specify the `type` attribute for value injection?

Comment: As @Sotirios Delimanolis said, sometimes the parameter/argument names are not available trough Reflection, and then the parameter types are used in order to match the correct parameter. Anyway, I would suggest you keep providing the parameter/constructor-arguments type, because it's more neat and readable, at least. :)